# Get all functions called (even if called by another function) libclang python

Tags: python, c++, libclang

I'm trying to use libclang/python 3.7 to gather every function called in a program by parsing it into a translation unit. I parse the main.cpp file in order to gather the data.

**Testhead.cpp**:

```
#include <testhead.h>
void a()
{
   std::cout<<5;
   b();
}
void b()
{
    std::cout<<6;
}
```

**Main.cpp**:

```
#include "testhead.h"

//classtest ct;

int main()
{
  a();
  return 0;
}
```

**OutPut**:
[I'm trying to get all function calls, noted by CALL_EXPR which is only given for function a() when function a() calls function b()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNRnl.png)

**Sample python/libclang used to get output**:

```
for i in node.get_children():
        if i.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.CALL_EXPR:
            print(str(i.kind)+","+i.spelling)
            #print(str(i.extent.start))
            tempSet.add(i.spelling)
        elif i.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL:
            print(str(i.kind)+","+i.spelling)
            #print(str(i.extent.start.file))
            for item in i.get_children():
                if item.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.CALL_EXPR:
                    tempSet.add(item.kind)
                    for n in item.get_children():
                        print(str(n.kind) +","+ n.spelling)
                        for z in n.get_children():
                            print(str(z.kind) +","+ z.spelling)
                elif item.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.COMPOUND_STMT:
                    print(' ' + str(item.kind) + ', ' + item.spelling)
                    #print(' ' + str(item.extent.start.file))
                    for c in item.get_children():
                        if c.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.CALL_EXPR:
                            print(' '*2 + str(c.kind) + ', ' + c.spelling+" , " + c.displayname)
                            #print(' '*2 + str(c.extent.start))
                            a = c.get_definition()
                            print(' '*10 + str(a))
                            tempSet.add(c.spelling)
                            for z in c.get_children():
                                print(' '*3 + str(z.kind) + ", "+ z.spelling)
                                a = z.get_definition()
                                print(' '*10 + str(a))
                                for x in z.get_children():
                                    print(' '*4 + str(x.kind) +","+ x.spelling)
                                    a = x.get_definition()
                                    print(' '*10 + str(a))
                                    for b in x.get_children():
                                        a = b.get_definition()
                                        print(' '*10 + str(a))
                                        print(' '*5 + str(b.kind) +","+ b.spelling)
```

Through trial and error I've found I'm only able find nested function calls inside function definitions that are defined in the main.cpp.

so far the only solution I have found is that I need to have an inclusion statement for the .h and .cpp 
eg:

```
#include <test.h>
#include <test.cpp>
main.cpp
..............
```

However I won't have access to the .cpp's, i will be using dll's

Comment: I think what you're asking for is impossible. You are only analyzing one translation unit, so you will only get the function calls within that translation unit. The fact that `a()` is implemented by calling `b()` has nothing to do with the `Main.cpp` translation unit. In fact, if `a()` is defined by a DLL, the internal functions it calls won't be known until runtime when the DLL is loaded. If you want to know what functions get called inside a DLL, you'll need to disassemble it to find out.

Comment: @DanielPryden Would it be possible if I were using .cpp files without using an inclusion statement?

Comment: The [`#include`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) is a pre-processor statement which is performed before the actual translation of code. I imagine it like `#include` is replaced by the referred file i.e. like copy/paste of code. (If you want to visualize this you have to call compiler with `-E` which outputs the pre-processed source code.) However, I'm not sure (I don't know) whether `#include`s are represented in the libclang AST at all. Btw. `#include <test.cpp>` in `main.cpp` is ugly bad style but makes effectively `test.cpp` a part of the translation unit `main.cpp`.

Comment: @magic_HAT: No, because that's what "translation unit" means: each translation unit is (basically) one `.cpp` file plus the headers it includes. C++ is designed around the idea that each translation unit is completely independent until linked together. With a dynamically linked library, that linking step doesn't happen until runtime. Therefore, whole-program analysis of the kind you're describing isn't possible using just a tool like clang. You either need to decompile all the libraries to find their symbols, or you need to join all the ASTs for all the translation units before analysis.

Comment: @scheff Thats why I wanted to avoid that, its very ugly, to clarify I was looking to gather the function definitions defined in a cpp into the main file I'm parseing that has the included headers without including the other cpp files. Do you know of any thing that may help with this?

Comment: @DanielPryden Thanks, I'm still relatively new with python and libclang. I'm still looking to get this functionality but not sure how to get there yet. Do you have any recommendations about how I might accomplish that? Or any useful articles that may help?

Comment: @magic_HAT: You need to clarify what you're trying to accomplish. What function calls do you actually care about, and why? In the general case, statically knowing all function calls that happen transitively from a given starting point is not just hard, it's completely impossible. More generally, knowing what any arbitrary program will do without running it is impossible (formally, undecidable). To prove the presence or absence of specific behaviors you need to constrain your problem set. You probably should read up on the Halting Problem and Rice's Theorem, for starters.

Comment: @DanielPryden Thanks for the information, I'll take a look at that, I'm looking for a specific set of custom functions, none that are a part of any preexisting library. Its for test automation for integration purposes.

Comment: @magic_HAT: If the library is getting statically linked into the DLL and then you're loading the DLL later, it's entirely possible that library functions are getting inlined into other functions. So it's possible that the functions you're looking for don't exist anymore by the time a DLL is built. If the library is itself a DLL, then the easiest way to see if anyone is calling it is by hooking the DLL. That's a dynamic rather than static mechanism, but for an integration test that might be exactly what you want.